# Not inserting in db while submitting the form using spring-mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, postgresql-9.3, spring-jdbc

Exception is The column index is out of range: 16, number of columns: 15.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 16, number of columns: 15. while submitting the form using this query. Kindly suggest. Your help will be appreciable.

@Override
    public int insertNewApplication(TokenApplicantDetails tpd)
    {

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO token_applicant_details"
            + "(application_no,applicant_name, applsex, "
            + "designation, date_of_superannuation, "
            + "phone_no, mobile_no, "
            + "office_type_code,ou_code,token_manufacturer_code,token_user_id,token_password, "
            +"certificate_no,certificate_issue_date,certificate_expiry_date, "
            +"fixed_ip_address,ref_no,form_type,original_application_receiving_date, "
            +"scanned_application_receiving_date,residential_address,staff_status, "
            +"email_id, enrollment_no, dispatch_no,fixed_ip_active, "
            +"refId,Deacivated_on) VALUES (null,?, ?, ?,to_date(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,null,null,null,null,null,?,null,null,?,?,?,null,null,null,null,null)";

    System.out.println("not inserted");
    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql,new Object[]{tpd.getApplication_no(),tpd.getApplicant_name(), tpd.getApplsex(),tpd.getDesignation(),tpd.getDate_of_superannuation(),tpd.getPhone_no(),tpd.getMobile_no(),
            tpd.getOffice_type_code(),tpd.getOu_code(),tpd.getToken_manufacturer_code(),tpd.getToken_user_id(),tpd.getToken_password(),tpd.getCertificate_no(),tpd.getCertificate_issue_date(),tpd.getCertificate_expiry_date(),
            tpd.getFixed_ip_address(),tpd.getRef_no(),tpd.getForm_type(),tpd.getOriginal_application_recieving_date(),
            tpd.getScanned_application_recieving_date(),tpd.getResidential_address(),tpd.getStaff_status(),
            tpd.getEmail_id(),tpd.getEnrollment_no(),tpd.getDispatch_no(),tpd.getFixed_ip_address(),tpd.getRefId(),tpd.getDeactivated_on(),});


}
```

Comment: You have different parameter count between sql and input parameter.

Comment: How? Can you please suggest how to correct it? Please tell in a detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your database table has 15 columns, whereas you are attempting to insert 16 values into the row. If I were you I'd tidy up the formatting of your query (e.g. one value per line) so that you can see better which value is mismatched.

Better would be to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate instead; this allows you to match up column values explicitly.